# Send dollar sign over SSH via Ruby system call

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'm trying to make a system call to SSH to a server and echo a string. The string is defined by ruby and has dollars signs in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
string = '$$%%$#@%$#@%325dg345345'

puts %x(ssh server "echo \'#{string}\'")
```

When I execute, the output that comes back is not the string. The remote server is interpreting the dollar signs as variable. Is there any form of clever escaping I can do to prevent this? The characters are random, so just editing the string to escape the dollar signs will not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the stdlib's [Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) library to escape not only the dollar signs, but also spaces and any other "dangerous" characters your string might have:

```
require 'shellwords'

string = '$$%%$#@%$#@%325dg345345'
escaped_string = Shellwords.escape(string)
# "\\$\\$\\%\\%\\$\\\#@\\%\\$\\\#@\\%325dg345345"

puts %x(ssh server "echo #{string}")
```

Comment: I figured there must be something like URL encode for shells, but didn't expect it to be in stdlib. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're opposed to escaping the `$`s, as it's perfectly doable whether the string is random or not:

```
escaped_string = string.gsub('$', '\$')
puts %x(ssh server "echo \'#{escaped_string}\'")
```

Outputs:

> $$%%$#@%$#@%325dg345345

Comment: That worked!! Not as elegant as i'd like, i figured there would be some way to escape the whole string but... I'll take it!